# Trouble conecting to Node Server on EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2

I have a Node application running on an EC2 instance, and after `npm start`, I am unable to connect to the application via the web, but everything indicates that it is running correctly.

Here's how my server.js looks like:

`app.listen(8000,"0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log("app running on port 8000"); 
});`

How are the inbound rules of the EC2 security group:

[image: EC2 Inbound Rules]

I saw on other sites that removing `" 0.0.0.0. "` From app.listen and leaving only the port would solve the problem, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Another thing I tried was to add a * Custom TCP * rule to port 8000 in the security group, but this prevented the application from running, saying that the port was already in use

Comment: Adding a Security Group role for the port 8000 is the right thing to do. It does not affect service, already running, so there is no need to start a new service on the same port - just try to access the one you already started.

Answer (score 0):

Something is already listening on port 8000, a `netstat` should tell you what it is.

Simply add a TCP security group for port 8001 or 8080 and in your code use that port instead.